# Проблемы с запросом

Tags: php, sql

Доброго вечера, изучаю PHP по книге O'Reilly, "Создание динамических веб-сайтов ...".
Разбирал приведённый в книге пример по работе с БД. Пример работает только частично, запросы на выборку информации выполняются нормально, а на удаление или добавление записей выводит ошибку:

```
 `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WREHE isbn=147258369147' at line 1
```

Через командную строку запросы выполняются нормально

Фрагменты кода:

```
$isbn = get_post($conn, "isbn");
$query = "DELETE FROM class WREHE isbn=$isbn";
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

---

```
$query = "INSERT INTO class(author, title, category, year, isbn) 
VALUES ('$author', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn')";
$result= $conn->query($query);
```

Просмотрел ответы на аналогичные вопросы, практически во всех случаях проблемы в ковычках (обратных). В моём случае добавление ковычек к class, isbn не помогает, ошибка остаётся.

Comment: все таки должно быть `WHERE` а не `WREHE`

Comment: На счет insert замечу только, что книгу с такими примерами стоило бы выбросить. это непонятно в каком году писалось и 70% всех взломов сайтов в мире происходят по вине такого кода, в котором значения непосредственно подставляются в текст запроса. Используйте привязываемые переменные http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Ошибку понял, надо быть внимательнее. Привязываемые переменные тоже рассмотрел, все работает.